# JS : Data being altered through exposed method?

Tags: javascript, closures

I couldn't find the similar question to this one, if there's one please guide me to the light.
I have following snippet of code:

```
var GUD = function() {
        var all = [1,2,3,4,5];

        return {
            getAll : function() {
                return all;
            }
        }
    }();
```

So a simple function hidding *all* variable and exposing the same through getAll method.
Why is it possible to alter the all array by using:

```
GUD.getAll() //[1, 2, 3, 4, 5] 
GUD.getAll().splice(0,1) //[1]
GUD.getAll() //[2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the edge cases where private variable protection fails is `when returning the reference types(including arrays)`.Instead of returning the actual reference of the object, try to return the copy of your object(in this case array).

There was a typo on my comment earlier (should been slice)

```
var GUD = function() {
    var all = [1,2,3,4,5];

    return {
        getAll : function() {
            return all.slice(0); // slice(0) creates a new copy of the array.
        }
    }
}();
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are returning the reference of the array. So when you are calling `splice` it's affecting both arrays

Return a copy of your array

```
var GUD = function() {
    var all = [1,2,3,4,5];

    return {
        getAll : function() {
            return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(all));
        }
    }
}();
```

Comment: thanks for an example.
So you make a json from the array object, once you compile it back it's an new Object not referenced anywhere.

Comment: What's bothering me is explained at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify under "Description".
Seems that there is a possibility to loose certain values if this approach is used?